# cmake でビルドしたライブラリを使う CMakeList の書き方

Tags: c++, build, cmake

Athena で読める ORC ファイルをクエリを使わずに生成したいです

`org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat`

というフォーマットでおそらく
https://github.com/apache/orc
これを使えばいいと思い

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/orc.git
cmake  -S orc -B orc/build -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF
cd orc/build
make package
make test-out
```

を実行したところ
~/homebrew/lib
~/homebrew/include
にいろいろ入りました

---

https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-cpp.html#writing-orc-files
次にこのサンプルを動かそうと以下の様な宣言部分だけかいてコンパイルしようとしました

main.cpp

```
#include <orc/OrcFile.hh>

int main() {
  ORC_UNIQUE_PTR<orc::OutputStream> outStream = orc::writeLocalFile("my-file.orc");
  ORC_UNIQUE_PTR<orc::Type> schema(
    orc::Type::buildTypeFromString("struct<x:int,y:int>"));
  orc::WriterOptions options;
  ORC_UNIQUE_PTR<orc::Writer> writer =
  createWriter(*schema, outStream.get(), options);
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
```

とかいて cmake . は通ったんですが make すると

```
fatal error: 'orc/OrcFile.hh' file not found
```

といわれます

cmake を初めて使ったのでインクルードやリンクを自動的にやってくれるものかと思ってたんですが、そういうものではないんでしょうか

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
```

というのを追加してみたところ main.cpp のコンパイルは通ったみたいでリンカーまでいったんですが

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/orc-test.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable orc-test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "orc::createWriter(orc::Type const&, orc::OutputStream*, orc::WriterOptions const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "orc::WriterOptions::WriterOptions()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "orc::WriterOptions::~WriterOptions()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "orc::writeLocalFile(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "orc::Type::buildTypeFromString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [orc-test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/orc-test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

というよくわからないエラーになりました

orc のインストールの時
share/doc/orc/LICENSE
share/doc/orc/NOTICE
と lib/ に *.a, include/ に *.hh がインストールされただけで、
cmake のコンフィグっぽいファイルはインストールされてるようにみえないんですが、
この cmake でビルドした orc を使うには CMakeLists.txt  にどうかけばいいんでしょうか？

昔うろ覚えなんですが aws-sdk-c++ を cmake でいれたときは
~/homebrew/lib/cmake/
に .cmake というファイルができてて
プロジェクト内の cmake ファイルもたいしたことかかなくても自動でインクルードやリンクをしてくれた記憶があるんですが…

---

追記です

CMakeList を以下の様に書いてみたところ

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
target_link_libraries(~/homebrew/lib/liborc.a)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
```

以下の様な警告が表示されます
その後 make の結果は変わらず同じエラーになります

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:6 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "~/homebrew/lib/liborc.a" which is
  not built by this project.

  CMake does not support this but it used to work accidentally and is being
  allowed for compatibility.

  Policy CMP0016 is not set: target_link_libraries() reports error if its
  only argument is not a target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0016" for
  policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
  suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

---

さらに追記です

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(orc-test liborc)
```

CMake を上の様に書いたところエラーが以下の様になりました

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable orc-test
ld: library not found for -lliborc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [orc-test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/orc-test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

あと気になるのはインストールされた
~/home/brew/lib/liborc.a
に実行権限がついてなかったです
chmod で実行権限をつけてもエラーはかわりませんでした

```
ls -l ~/homebrew/lib/liborc.a
-rw-r--r--  1 xxxxx  xxxxx  21913912  2 18 23:07 /Users/xxxxx/homebrew/lib/liborc.a
```

でファイルは間違いなく存在してます

---

追記3

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(orc-test
    orc
    snappy
    protobuf
    protoc
    lz4
    zstd
    z
    Threads::Threads
)
```

こうかえてみたんですがやはりエラーになります

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "hdfs::FileSystem::New(hdfs::IoService*&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, hdfs::Options const&)", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::ConfigParser::LoadDefaultResources()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::ConfigParser::ConfigParser()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::ConfigParser::~ConfigParser()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::parse_from_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::URI()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::Options::Options()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::StatInfo::StatInfo()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::IoService::New()", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::ConfigParser::get_options(hdfs::Options&) const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::ConfigParser::ValidateResources() const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::str(bool) const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::get_host(bool) const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::get_path(bool) const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::get_port() const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::URI::has_port() const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
  "hdfs::Status::ToString() const", referenced from:
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::read(void*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
      orc::HdfsFileInputStream::HdfsFileInputStream(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in liborc.a(OrcHdfsFile.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

エラー内容は同じなんですがエラーを起こす場所
orc::createWriter ではなく hdfs::FileSystem にかわりました

そもそもこんなライブラリが使われてることはどうすればわかるんでしょうか…

うまくいったときのコンパイルコマンドを教えていただけないでしょうか

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/bzip2/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/mysql/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/libxml2/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/readline/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib -L$HOME/homebrew/opt/gettext/lib CMakeFiles/orc-test.dir/main.cpp.o -o orc-test   -L$HOME/homebrew/lib  -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/homebrew/lib -lorc -lsnappy -lprotobuf -lprotoc -llz4 -lzstd -lz
```

自分の環境ではこういうコマンドでコンパイルしようとしています
.zshrc に余計なことをかいてしまってるせいなんでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

ライブラリのパスが設定されていないからではないですか？
これを追加してみてください。

```
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
```

追記
`target_link_libraries` は `add_executable` の後に記載する必要があります。
こちらで試してみてください。

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(orc-test orc)
```

追記2
手元でビルドまで確認してみました。
指定ライブラリが不足していたのと、`pthread`の追加が必要でした。
ライブラリの追加には依存関係上、記載の順番がありますので(おそらくorcを一番上にしておけば大丈夫)気をつけてください。

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
include_directories(~/homebrew/include)
link_directories(~/homebrew/lib)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(orc-test
    orc
    snappy
    protobuf
    protoc
    lz4
    zstd
    z
    Threads::Threads
)
```

追記3
アーキテクチャでのエラーが見受けられますがビルドしたライブラリを参照できていますか？
こちらはCentOS7でのビルド確認ですが、Macでも同じだと思います。
ビルド後にパッケージングされたライブラリを使えばエラーにはならないはずです。

ORCのビルド

```
$ cd orc
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF
$ make package
$ make test-out
$ mv ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux.tar.gz ~/.
$ cd ~/
$ tar xfz ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux.tar.gz
$ cd ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux/
```

ここまででビルドしたパッケージの中にいるはずです。
`main.cpp` と `CMakeLists.txt` をここに置いてください。

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ ./orc-test
$ cat my-file.orc
ORC
```

`orc-test` ができているので実行すると `my-file.orc` が生成されているはずです。

`CMakeLists.txt` の中身も置いておきます。質問者さんのコンパイルコマンドに `-lpthread` がないですが、`find_package`と`Threads::Threads`の追加をしていますか？

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(orc-test CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
include_directories(~/ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux/include)
link_directories(~/ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux/lib)
add_executable(orc-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(orc-test
    orc
    snappy
    protobuf
    protoc
    lz4
    zstd
    z
    Threads::Threads
)
```

コンパイルコマンドも載せておきます。

```
/usr/bin/c++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/orc-test.dir/main.cpp.o -o orc-test   -L/home/user/ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ORC-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT-Linux/lib -lorc -lsnappy -lprotobuf -lprotoc -llz4 -lzstd -lz -lpthread
```

Comment: ダメでした。そもそも.a しかできてなくて .dylib ができてないのでライブラリ側のインストールに問題がある気がしてきました…

Comment: .aは静的ライブラリなのでそれを取り込めばいいと思います。add_executable()のあとにtarget_link_libraries(orc-test 取り込みたいライブラリ.a)でリンクできませんか？

Comment: @KTI あ、.aはいらないです

Comment: target_link_libraries(orc-test 取り込みたいライブラリ)これでいけると思います

Comment: ダメでした。長くなりそうなので追記してみました。出てるエラーのソースコードが自分が書いた部分ではないのでライブラリに必要な別の何かが足りてないんでしょうか

Comment: @KTI target_link_libraries は add_executable の後に記載する必要があります。回答に追加したので試してみてください。

Comment: @KTI liborc → orc に変えてやってみてください

Comment: @KTI 手元でビルドまでやってみました。色々ライブラリ指定が抜けていたのでエラーになっていたようです。追記2にビルドできたものを記載しておきました。

Comment: 何度もすみません…　やはりだめなようです。あとさすがに時間使い過ぎなと python にも orc が書けるライブラリ(https://pypi.org/project/pyorc/ )をみつけたので書き直すことにしました…　せかっく何度も回答いただいたのにもうしわけありません

Comment: @KTI とりあえず細かくビルドまでの作業を書いておきました。必要であれば使ってください。

Answer (score 1):

CMakeを使ったプロジェクトでライブラリの依存関係に困ったときは、[vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)に任せてしまうという手があります。

[例](https://github.com/tueda/test-apache-orc)をGitHubに作ってみました。
以下のようにクローン・ビルドできます（依存しているライブラリをすべてダウンロード・ビルドするので少し時間が掛かります）：

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/tueda/test-apache-orc.git
cd test-apache-orc
cmake .
make
```

ポイントは、

- `vcpkg`をGitのサブモジュールとしてインポートしている。
- `vcpkg.json`の中で直接に依存しているライブラリを指定する（この場合は`orc`のみ）。

```js
{
  "name": "test-apache-orc",
  "version-string": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": [
    "orc"
  ]
}
```

- `CMakeLists.txt`の最初（`project(...)`の前）に`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`を設定することで、サブモジュールとして導入したvcpkgを使わせる。

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
    CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")
```

- 残念ながら`orc` ([1.6.4](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/99dc49dae7e170c3be63dd097230007f3bb73c4f/ports/orc/CONTROL))はCMake用のターゲットを用意してくれてないので、`CMakeLists.txt`にいろいろと依存ライブラリを`target_link_libraries(...)`で書く必要があります。ただし、何を書けばよいかは`vcpkg`が教えてくれます（というか[先人の知恵](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/99dc49dae7e170c3be63dd097230007f3bb73c4f/ports/orc/usage)です）。

```sh
$ ./vcpkg/vcpkg install orc

...

The package orc does not provide CMake targets:

    find_package(protobuf CONFIG REQUIRED)
    find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
    find_package(Snappy CONFIG REQUIRED)

    find_library(LZ4_LIBRARY NAMES lz4d lz4)
    find_library(ZSTD_LIBRARY NAMES zstd)
    find_library(ORC_LIBRARY NAMES orc)

    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${ORC_LIBRARY} protobuf::libprotoc protobuf::libprotobuf Snappy::snappy ${LZ4_LIBRARY} ${ZSTD_LIBRARY} ZLIB::ZLIB)
```